# StreamWriter data getting lost on a reboot

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using `StreamWriter` to write a file in a sessionchange like logon and logoff.

But if a reboot happens just about the time when we write/close the file, we are getting an empty file and some time data already in it is getting deleted
This is my code

```
public void ToJson(T objectToWrite)
        {
            InformFileLogger.Instance.Debug(">>> start >>>");
            try
            {
                string json = null;
                string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.serializeFilePath);
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }

                if (File.Exists(this.serializeFilePath))
                {
                    if (new FileInfo(this.serializeFilePath).Length == 0)
                    {
                        File.Delete(this.serializeFilePath);
                    }
                }

                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);

                if (json != null)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.serializeFilePath))
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(json);
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                InformEventLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
                InformFileLogger.Instance.Error(InformHelper.ExceptionMessageFormat(ex));
            }

            InformFileLogger.Instance.Debug("<<< end <<<");
        }
```

How can I avoid writing null entries in the files/ getting the data deleted?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how the reboot is triggered.

Unless the reboot is triggered by your code, you won't be able to make sure your code can do *anything* before a reboot - including completing a StreamWriter function.

Comment: Actually my problem is the file is getting writed but instead of original string whitespaces are writing (sorry for my bad eng)

Comment: If that is the case, then you'll need to expand your troubleshooting, and check if objectToWrite has a structure you'd expect. Also, you'll need to verify that JsonConvert.SerializeObject is serializing as you'd expect.